# how to automate load obj, turn, view all and save via python in background mode?

Tags: python, objects, import, file-format

How to execute  import obj file 
turn it as if calling view left/right/top/...
perform view all (so that it fit a given area)
and save result to to disk?

so far I figured out how to do load and save by calling:

```
blender --background --python obj-to-jpg.py
```

where obj-to.jpg.py is

```
import bpy
inputFilePath = "/path/to/big.obj"
outputFilePath = "/path/to/big.jpg"
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = outputFilePath
bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
```

Any help is much appreciated!